# Android Data Binding: make element invisible every binding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I need to hide an image every time binding is performed. 
If I add `visibility` attribute to item in layout like this

```
android:visibility="@{View.INVISIBLE}"
```

It doesn't work. But if I try like this

```
android:visibility="@{myBindingVariableName == null ? View.INVISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"
```

It works. Tell me please if it can be done in more simple way.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide that view why even databinding is needed? Directly hide it as we do it.

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

and if you really want to use databinding and want your view to behave based on variable value than as you said your code is working with

```
android:visibility="@{myBindingVariableName == null ? View.INVISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"
```